# How to change screening (halftone pattern) of my printer Cups driver?

Tags: cups, ghostscript, postscript

I am using CUPS with the printer driver which use "application/vnd.cups-raster 10 rastertopj" and i am trying to get the look of dither 4x4 print/output but i am clueless where to change the setting for choosing different dithering/halftoning pattern..

i also contacted the cups and they said dithering is done by the driver and also told that If the driver is Ghostscript-based you may be able to change the dither as you’d like, and yes this is indeed Ghostscript-based printer driver/filter cause when i open .PPD file i see *Product:    "(ESP Ghostscript)".

Can you please guide me on how or where to change the dither of the printer filter/driver?

Edited:
this is the halftone output its printing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHORa.jpg or https://imgur.com/download/7pTksX4

this is the output i am looking for: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryzUF.jpg or https://imgur.com/download/5FnpKEM

Thankyou